# GraphQL - Join results of two queries

Tags: graphql

I'm pretty new to GraphQL and trying to learn how I can use it to model my results.

Currently I have these two types. The `owner_user_id` is referring to the id in the User-type

```js
ProductTeam {
    id: Int!
    product_name: String
    product_description: String
    owner_user_id: Int!
}

type User {
    id: Int!
    first_name: String
    last_name: String
    email: String
    username: String
}
```

Can I somehow get a merged nice response here like below? Do I use fragments?

```js
ProductTeam {
    id: 1
    product_name: ""
    product_description: ""
    owner_user_id: 2
    first_name: ""
    last_name: ""
    email: ""
    username: ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that ProductTeam also means a type in you schema (the ID could not be a number like "1")...

I would go like this:

```
type ProductTeam {
    id: ID
    product_name: String
    product_description: String
    user: User!
}

type User {
    id: Int!
    first_name: String
    last_name: String
    email: String
    username: String
}
```

and if there is something like this to query teams:

```
extend type Query {
    findTeam(teamId: ID!): ProductTeam
}
```

then you can query e.g.:

```
findTeam(teamId:1){
    id
    product_name
    product_description
    user {
        id
        first_name
        last_name
        email
        username
    }
}
```

So, from the view of the graphql query there is no explicit foreign key/join column. But your backend (the graphql server) needs a property called `user` that is filled by joining the user using `owner_user_id`.

*update*

Although this is not the idea of GraphQL and therefore I would not recommend it, you could do the following alternatives:

second option:

Using the resolver in the backend. Then you can either create a new combined type called "ProductTeamWithUser", which includes all properties and your resolver fills the result.
Or you extend the ProductTeam type in the GraphQL schema with optional properties from the user and the resolver fetches the user and and provides the properties for the productTeam like first_name.

third option:

Do it in your frontend. You can fetch the team and copy the result of the data into the product team object. But I think, you'll need two requests to get the `owner_user_id` first and the user-data in a second request. Avoiding exactly this is one of the main reasons why graphQL was created. Therefore: also no recommendation.

Comment: My last code snippet is referring to the wanted JSON response

Comment: added some updates. It would be more convenient to model and use a graph with GraphQL and then, if necessary, to map properties in the frontend

Comment: Also the FK joins are ProductTeam:owner_user_id referring to User:id. Also someone edited my post and did som changes that I need to correct

Comment: What I'm after is a flat response. A nested response is no problem. That has already been solved

Comment: Then you need to model a flat type and a resolver needs to do the join. In GraphQL there are only predefined relations defined by the schema. therefore you cannot model such a join in a query on the fly like in SQL.